# Integrating Spring security with JSF 2

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have developed a JSF Web application , now i am trying to integrate it with spring security, but it was not as simple as i thought, here are some code :

this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                        version="3.0">
  <display-name>azraspina</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<!-- ############################################# -->
<!-- # File upload                               # -->
<!-- ############################################# -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>51200</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>



<!-- ############################################# -->
<!-- # Spring Security                           # -->
<!-- ############################################# -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>     
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/classes/spring-database.xml,
            /WEB-INF/classes/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

and this is spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.xhtml" />
        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationProcessingFilter" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />


    <beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler"
            ref="failureHandler" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            ref="successHandler" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="successHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.xhtml" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="failureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/index.xhtml" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/index.xhtml" />
        <beans:property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="
                    select username,password, enabled 
                    from users where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="
                    select u.username, r.authority from users u, roles r, user_roles ur 
                    where u.user_id = ur.user_id and r.role_id = ur.role_id and u.username =?    " />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


</beans:beans>
```

should be any configurations about spring-security in faces-config.xml? because i dont have any.

this is the error i am getting now (with some debug notes),

```
[DEBUG][10:57:20,265] [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment:112  Initializing new StandardServletEnvironment
[DEBUG][10:57:20,267] [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment:107  Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
[DEBUG][10:57:20,267] [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment:107  Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
[DEBUG][10:57:20,272] [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment:107  Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
[DEBUG][10:57:20,272] [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment:107  Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
[DEBUG][10:57:20,273] [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment:107  Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
[DEBUG][10:57:20,273] [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment:116  Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
[INFO][10:57:20,275] [localhost-startStop-1] XmlWebApplicationContext:510  Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Oct 23 10:57:20 IRST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
[DEBUG][10:57:20,279] [localhost-startStop-1] StandardServletEnvironment:172  Replacing [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with [servletContextInitParams]
[DEBUG][10:57:20,327] [localhost-startStop-1] StandardEnvironment:112  Initializing new StandardEnvironment
[DEBUG][10:57:20,328] [localhost-startStop-1] StandardEnvironment:107  Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
[DEBUG][10:57:20,328] [localhost-startStop-1] StandardEnvironment:107  Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
[DEBUG][10:57:20,328] [localhost-startStop-1] StandardEnvironment:116  Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
[INFO][10:57:20,339] [localhost-startStop-1] XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315  Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/spring-database.xml]
[DEBUG][10:57:20,341] [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultDocumentLoader:72  Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
[DEBUG][10:57:20,365] [localhost-startStop-1] PluggableSchemaResolver:140  Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
[DEBUG][10:57:20,369] [localhost-startStop-1] PluggableSchemaResolver:146  Loaded schema mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.2.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd}
[DEBUG][10:57:20,370] [localhost-startStop-1] PluggableSchemaResolver:118  Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
[DEBUG][10:57:20,411] [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader:106  Loading bean definitions
[DEBUG][10:57:20,432] [localhost-startStop-1] XmlBeanDefinitionReader:216  Loaded 1 bean definitions from location pattern [/WEB-INF/classes/spring-database.xml]
[INFO][10:57:20,432] [localhost-startStop-1] XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315  Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/spring-security.xml]
[DEBUG][10:57:20,433] [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultDocumentLoader:72  Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
[DEBUG][10:57:20,435] [localhost-startStop-1] PluggableSchemaResolver:118  Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
[DEBUG][10:57:20,458] [localhost-startStop-1] PluggableSchemaResolver:118  Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.1.xsd
[DEBUG][10:57:20,510] [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader:106  Loading bean definitions
[DEBUG][10:57:20,512] [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver:156  Loaded NamespaceHandler mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/p=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee=org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop=org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc=org.springframework.jdbc.config.JdbcNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache=org.springframework.cache.config.CacheNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/c=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security=org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx=org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task=org.springframework.scheduling.config.TaskNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang=org.springframework.scripting.config.LangNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context=org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler}
[INFO][10:57:20,519] [localhost-startStop-1] SpringSecurityCoreVersion:33  You are running with Spring Security Core 3.1.4.RELEASE
[INFO][10:57:20,519] [localhost-startStop-1] SecurityNamespaceHandler:59  Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.1.4.RELEASE
[INFO][10:57:20,596] [localhost-startStop-1] HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser:264  Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, <authenticationProcessingFilter>, order = 800, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1800, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1900, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2000]
[DEBUG][10:57:20,607] [localhost-startStop-1] XmlBeanDefinitionReader:216  Loaded 28 bean definitions from location pattern [/WEB-INF/classes/spring-security.xml]
[DEBUG][10:57:20,608] [localhost-startStop-1] XmlWebApplicationContext:540  Bean factory for Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2deeb609: defining beans [dataSource,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#3,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#5,authenticationProcessingFilter,successHandler,failureHandler,authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint,org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
[DEBUG][10:57:20,640] [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultListableBeanFactory:374  Ignoring bean class loading failure for bean 'authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint'
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint] for bean with name 'authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/spring-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:434)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1267)
    ... 19 more
[DEBUG][10:57:20,651] [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultListableBeanFactory:374  Ignoring bean class loading failure for bean 'authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint'
```

Comment: Which Spring Security version are you using? [AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint.html) is marked as deprecated and probably removed in newest versions of Spring Security. You should use [LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.html) instead.

Comment: @XtremeBiker i am using 3.1.4.RELEASE

Comment: @XtremeBiker actually you were right .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED.

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/index.xhtml" />
    <beans:property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
</beans:bean>
```

as Xtreme Biker mentioned in a comment,  **AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint** is deprecated so i changed it to **LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint** and that solved this problem. 
thank you Biker ;)